# AVA testing problems

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, ava

I am trying to write a test using [AVA](https://github.com/sindresorhus/ava) but I can't seem to get it to work write. `fn` passes the callback function through all of my functions and calls it once it's done everything. My test is

```
import test from 'ava';
import fn from './index.js';

test('NonLiteral && Literal', function (t) {
  fn('test.txt', '', function (res) {
    console.log(res);
    t.is(res, '');
  });
});
```

The res is

```
This is a test
How is it going
So far!!!
```

but it is saying that my test is passing. I've been following [this](https://github.com/sindresorhus/ava/blob/master/test/cli.js) test. Here is the snippet I've been looking at

```
test('throwing a named function will report the to the console', function (t) {
    execCli('fixture/throw-named-function.js', function (err, stdout, stderr) {
        t.ok(err);
        t.match(stderr, /\[Function: fooFn]/);
        // TODO(jamestalmage)
        // t.ok(/1 uncaught exception[^s]/.test(stdout));
        t.end();
    });
});
```

Can someone explain to me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorry for the confusion, unfortunately that unit test you are looking at uses `tap`, not AVA. (AVA does not use itself for testing ... yet).

I am guessing that `fn` is async. In that case, you probably want to use `test.cb`.

```
test.cb('NonLiteral && Literal', function (t) {
    fn('test.txt', '', function (res) {
        console.log(res);
        t.is(res, '');
        t.end();
    });
});
```

Now, it looks like maybe `fn` will call that callback more than once, but it is an error to call `t.end()` more than once. If that is so, you will need to do something like this:

```
test.cb('NonLiteral && Literal', function (t) {
    var expected = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];
    var i = 0;
    fn('test.txt', '', function (res) {
        t.is(res, expected[i]);
        i++;
        if (i >= expected.length) {
            t.end();
        }
    });
});
```

Finally, I would encourage you to consider implementing a Promise based api so you can take advantage of `async` functions and the `await` keyword. It ends up creating much cleaner code than callbacks. In situations where you want to call a callback multiple times, consider Observables. Testing strategies for both are documented in the AVA docs. Further info on Observables is pretty easy to find by Googling.

Thanks for trying AVA. Keep those questions coming!

Comment: Ya I noticed that it was using tap and that helped sort a lot out. I ended up figuring out the first solution you provided. I also tried redoing my code with promises but since I am literally just now learning them I haven't gotten that working yet. Thanks for the response, much more in depth than what I was going to answer with.